# Trying to easeoutsine a div with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I made the following script:

The div i want to animate:

```
DIV = $('div.info_holder');
```

And the function:

```
function bezar(){

DIV.stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 400,
            easing: "easeOutSine",
            complete: function () {
               DIV.css("display", "none")
            }
        })};
```

Why I'm not able to get this work? :)

Comment: try `console.log(DIV)` inside the function and see what there is

Comment: And where does it do the log? :)

Comment: in your browser's developer tools JS console - in a webkit browser like Chrome/Safari press Control-Shift-J on a PC or ⌥⌘J on a Mac

Answer (score 3):

are you sure `easeOutSine` is available to you as an easing function (ie you are using jQ UI or some other easing plugin)? While `.animate()` is part of jQuery core the additional easing functions are not.

If you just want easeOutSine do something like:

```
$.extend($.easing,
  {
    easeOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
      return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
    }
  }
)
```

in your JavaScript before you call `animate()` and that should work.